# Expo start shows “Starting Metro Bundler” forever on Android Device

Tags: javascript, react-native, mobile, expo

Expo start shows “Starting Metro Bundler” forever

And Expo Client shows a white blank screen on the android  device

Not showing any error or logs.

have tried `expo install` plus `expo start`  many times but the same result appears every time

Comment: I have the same issue, do you have any solution by now?